# Bypass Google Two Factor authentication

Tags: authentication

I Use Google two factor authentication in my site but I want to be able users that check 'remember me', don't need to enter key on next entry. Is it possible to bypass the authentication by 'remember me' option. I know potential dangers but we need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will still be of help but I thought I would answer anyway. You haven't specified what programming language you're using, which makes it a little difficult to give you a language specific answer, for this reason I'll basing my answer on my experience writing a [C# ASP.NET MVC Two Factor Authentication](http://satalketo.com/2013/09/mvc-two-factor-authentication/) implementation, but the approach should be language agnostic.

There is nothing to stop you from implementing a 'remember me' feature that allows the user to bypass the whole authentication step (username/password + TFA). It actually isn't any different than any other 'remember me' feature that you would implement assuming the two factor authentication has been implemented correctly.

By implementing two factor authentication correctly what I mean is that your login should be a two step process (you can do it in one but it decreases usability and for the sake of explanation I'm going to keep them separate)

1. The user specifies their username and password. If they provide a valid username/password combination then they are passed on to step two but they are **NOT** yet authenticated! They should not be able to navigate to any page that requires the user to be logged in.
2. The user specifies their second factor. Only if the user provides the right second factor should they be authenticated and allowed to continue.

In my code I had the 'remember me' check box in step one, then if the user provided a valid username/password combination I would store the UserProfile object and whether the 'remember me' was checked in the session and redirect the user to the second factor page.

Then if the user provides the correct second factor for the user that is stored in the session then you log the user in, if they checked 'remember me' then add an expiration date to the cookie, otherwise leave it with an empty expiration date which will then expire when the browser closes down.

Hopefully that answers your question, I've tried not to reproduce the entire article from my website here so feel free to check that out if you think I've missed something, if you still don't have the answer let me know and I'll update my answer.